# Navigation in WebView with keyboard

Tags: android, webview, keyevent

Is it possible to navigate through elements in WebView? For example if web page contains 3x3 grid with buttons, is it possible to select and press these buttons using key events?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.You can enable javascript for your WebViewClass.Please check this : https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#NavigatingHistory

Comment: Yes.This is how you can enable javascript https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#EnablingJavaScript